# MikroTik и внутренний OpenVPN сервер

Tags: openvpn, mikrotik

Имеется следующая сеть:

- 172.31.0.2 - MikroTik CHR;
- 172.31.0.9 - OpenVPN сервер на базе Pritunl;
- 172.31.0.10 - Windows Server 2019

На Pritunl настроена сеть для клиентов 172.31.1.0/24. А на MikroTik указан маршрут 172.31.1.0/24 на шлюз 172.31.0.9.

В работе выявилась следующая проблема: с клиентских ПК (например 172.31.1.2) всё работает отлично - ping ходит, RDP-подключение работает. Но если попробовать сделать ping на клиента, то он не проходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось так: сервер OpenVPN (Pritunl) NAT-ил подключения от клиентов.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN сервер имеет доступ к внутренней сети микротика. У него есть свой адрес 172.31.0.9. Он от своего лица и пингует сеть 172.31.0.0/24.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы всё действовало аналогично для микротик, он должен иметь свой выделенный IP адрес (например 172.31.1.66). И как подставное лицо пинговать сеть 172.31.1.0/24.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В микротик это будет как второй поставщик интернета. И по адресам 172.31.1.0/24 он должен делать маскарадинг на этот бридж.

Comment: Без регистрации MT клиентом OpenVPN никак?

Comment: Если бы были два микротика, то можно было бы сделать туннель из одной сети в другую. Но как подружить OpenVPN с MikroTik не знаю. Входящий запрос дайте поговорить с адресом 172.31.1.x/24 из сети 172.31.0.0/24 не поймут, уйдёт в мусорку. Ответные данные будут с обратным адресом 172.31.0.9 и без уточнения какой клиент из сети 172.31.1.x/24 ответил. Всё скрыто.

Comment: Дошло... Клиентом OpenVPN можно не быть. Нужно просто, чтобы был выделенный IP в сети 172.31.1.0/24 для MikroTik.